# Always on Top in Wayland

Tags: wayland, 19.04

When I log in Ubuntu in Wayland checking always on top in any application the right click menu is showing below the app window. I am using Ubuntu 19.04. Is that problem with my laptop or it is a bug in 19.04.[image: files]
[image: terninal]

It happening only in **Ubuntu on Wayland** and only when checking **Always on top**.
It is not happening with snap apps.

Comment: Possibly a bug.

Comment: Does this happening for you too?